# Zombie apocalypse systems that use lots of d10

Tags: game-recommendation, zombies

Yet another system recommendation question from me. While procrastinating at work, I stumbled upon a very poorly written "Zombie Apocalypse Guide" and immediately got fascinated by the idea to run a short campaign in that theme.

- Ideally, it should rely on lots of d10 dice. If it does not, it should be possible to adapt it to use d10s.
- Quick battle/skill resolution, preferably including mechanics or table for persistent wounds
- What I am looking for in terms of gameplay is primarily scavenging for resources, setting up defenses, interaction with other players/NPCs of people who are suddenly caught by zombies
- I don't want an expansion to a general-colossus system like DnD, Savage Worlds, GURPS etc. I am looking for either an indie game or a system made with zombie apocalypse at mind

I am most interested in the first and third points - I have a heck-a-lot of d10 (because I also play *The Riddle of Steel* occasionally) and I'd like to have another use for them. Plus, both I and my players enjoy rolling a handful (or three) of dice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[All Flesh Must Be Eaten](http://www.allflesh.com/flesh.html) is the huge zombie apocalypse RPG, and it uses Eden Studios' [Unisystem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unisystem) which is d10 based. Any given roll only uses one or two, but since there are often hordes of zombies your d10s all get their exercise.

It is a BIG game line that has something for every subgenre (Kung fu zombies!  Wild West zombies! Pirate zombies!  Military zombies!). And it's loads of fun, a reasonably light system.